# Historical connections between "carnival" and "cannibalism"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history, phonology, historical-change

This may be a somewhat disturbing question, but as a non-native speaker, the word *carnival* seems very similar to a totally different word called *cannibalism*.

I’m well aware of the difference between those two words, but I always wonder there are any underlying (historical) reasons that those two words happen to be similar at least in terms of the pronunciation.

Comment: Here, you can look up the etymologies of the two words and see if they're related. Carnival: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival#Etymology . Cannibalism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_cannibalism#Etymology . Dictionaries seem to be positively give the etymology of carnival as removing or taking away of meat, however Wikipedia says it's a folk etymology, and gives other possibilities.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Carnival misrepresented its source, and I have edited it. The source says that _carne vale_ "farewell to meat" is a folk etymology, but _carne levare_ "remove meat" is not.

Comment: @ColinFine Often these summaries on Wikipedia so abbreviate their original sources as to obscure or even negate the original. That’s why I’ve given more detailed notes below.

Answer (score 5):

#### Summary

This is a mere coincidence of convergent phonological evolution, not of common etymons.

- *Cannibal* has nothing to do with the Great Khan nor with dogs, let alone with meat. Rather, it’s about the Caribbean autochthons.
- *Carnival* has nothing to do with saying farewell although it does have a *meat*-meaning etymon.

---

## Of Xanadu and meat’s goodbye

The OED makes clear that *cannibal* and *carnival* have nothing to do with one another. They also provide some notes about longstanding but erroneous folk etymologies.

For example, Columbus even thought *cannibals* were related in name to the Great Khan of Asia, or at least, wanted others to think that: he wrote that *Caniba* was nothing but the people of the Great Khan.

Another fanciful folk etymology from the 1500s was to try to connect *cannibal* to Latin *canis* meaning ‘dog’. [The OED writes](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/27102?rskey=5Tq7xf&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> ## cannibal
>
> **Etymology**: In 16th cent. plural *Canibales*, < Spanish *Canibales*, originally one of the forms of the ethnic name Carib or Caribes, a fierce nation of the West Indies, who are recorded to have been *anthropophagi*, and from whom the name was subsequently extended as a descriptive term.
>
> > Professor J. H. Trumbull, of Hartford, has pointed out that *l, n, r* interchange dialectally in American languages, whence the variant forms *Caniba, Caribe, Galibi*: and that Columbus’s first representation of the name as he heard it from the Cubans was *Canibales*, explained as ‘los de Caniba or Canima’; when he landed on Hayti, he heard the name of the people as *Caribes* and their country *Carib* ; the latter was afterwards identified with Puerto Rico, named by the Spaniards ‘Isla de Carib’, ‘which in some islands’, Columbus says, ‘they call *Caniba*, but in Hayti *Carib*’. Apparently, however, it was only foreigners who made a place-name out of that of the people: according to Oviedo (*Hist. Gen.* ɪɪ. viii.) *caribe* signifies ‘brave and daring’, with which Prof. Trumbull compares the Tupi *caryba* ‘superior man, hero, *vir*’. *Calib*- (in Caliban *n*.) is apparently another variant = *carib-an*; compare *Galibi* above-mentioned.
> >
> > Columbus’s notion on hearing of *Caniba* was to associate the name with the Grand Khan, whose dominions he believed to be not far distant; he held ‘que Caniba no es otra cosa sino la gente del Gran Can’. To connect the name with Spanish *can*, Italian *cane*, Latin *canis* dog, was a later delusion, entertained by Geraldini, Bp. of San Domingo, 1521–5; it naturally tickled the etymological fancy of the 16th cent., and may have helped to perpetuate the particular form *canibal* in association with the sense *anthropophagi*. See Prof. Trumbull's article, in *Notes & Queries* 5th Ser. IV. 171.

The Spanish cognate *caníbal* with unnatural stress is one of those *r/n/l* phonological swaps that the OED mentions: the [DRAE says](http://dle.rae.es/?id=78qXat5) it’s from *caríbal*, and that from *caribe*.

So there is no legitimate etymon behind *cannibal* that is in any way related to [the Latin word for meat: *caro/carnis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caro#Latin), the one we get words like *carnal* and *incarnate* from.

## Of incarnate matters

However, in the case of *carnival*, there indeed is such. Just not in the way the folk etymologies would have it. This word has enjoyed a variety of spellings in English, starting with *carnoval, carnevale* during the 1500s, then all of *carnevall, carnivale, carnivall, carnaval, carnival* during the 1600s. Of those five, only the last two survived into the 1700s, and after that only *carnival* alone.

Well, in English.  Spanish, Portuguese, Catalan, and French all still spell it *carnaval*, while Italian has *carnevale*, about which Wiktionary says it is:

> From Latin *carnem levāre* ("take away/remove meat"). Compare Old Italian *carnasciale* ("carnival") from *carnem laxāre*, Romanian *cârneleagă* from *carnem ligat*, and Spanish *carnestolendas* (“three days preceding the beginning of Lent”) from *carnis tollendus*. Other theories suggest it comes from Latin *carnealis* ("meaty") or *carnualis* ("feast").

Indeed, Spanish still uses *carnestolendas* to mean Shrovetide(s), which are the three days immediately preceding Lent: Shrove Sunday, Shrove Monday, and Shrove Tuesday, where Lent begins on Ash Wednesday. The Spanish *carnaval* is said to be from the Italian, where we learn that the old *carne + levare* was originally a calque of the Greek *ἀπόκρεως apókreōs*. The [*Diccionario de la Real Academia Española*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7bcNniL) says:

> Del it. *carnevale*, haplología del ant. *carnelevare*, de carne ‘carne¹’ y levare ‘quitar’, calco del gr. *ἀπόκρεως apókreōs*.

We get a bit more translation of the postclassical Greek *apókreōs* meaning ‘meat abstinence’ in [the Spanish Wiktionary entry for *carnaval*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/carnaval):

> Del italiano *carnevale*, contracción de *carnelevale*, y este de *carne levare* ("dejar la carne"), siguiendo el modelo del latín medieval *carnelevarium, carnilevamen*, y este calcando el griego postclásico *ἀπόκρεως* (*apókreōs*, "abstinente de carne"). Compárese *carnestolendas* o el italiano *carnasciale*, que muestran evoluciones análogas, así como el francés *carnaval*, el inglés *carnival* o el portugués *carnaval*, tomados del italiano. **La versión que lo deriva de un supuesto latín *carnem vale* (‘adiós a la carne’) carece de sustento histórico y etimológico.**

The sentence at the end that I’ve set in bold says that the folk etymology is, in effect, completely bogus. So everybody agrees this came from Italian, and that it has nothing to do with saying See ya! to meat.

However it is spelled, [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28104?redirectedFrom=carnival#eid) consigns attempts to connect *carnival* to Latin *vale* for ‘farewell’ to the realm of ‘popular etymology’:

> ## carnival
>
> **Etymology**: < Italian *carnevale, carnovale* (whence French *carnaval*), evidently related to the medieval Latin (11–12th cent.) names *carnelevārium, carnilevāria, carnilevāmen*, cited by Carpentier in additions to Du Cange. These appear to originate in a Latin **carnem levāre*, or Italian **carne levare* (with infinitive used substantively as in *il levar del sole* sunrise), meaning ‘the putting away or removal of flesh (as food)’, the name being originally proper to the eve of Ash Wednesday. The actual Italian *carnevale* appears to have come through the intermediate *carnelevale*, cited by Carpentier from a document of 1130.
>
> > The history of the word is illustrated by the parallel medieval Latin name *carnem laxare* (cited by Carpentier from a charter of 1050), corresponding to Italian **carne lasciare* ‘leaving or forsaking flesh’, whence, apparently by contraction, the modern *carnasciale* = *carnevale*. **Carnem laxare, *carne lasciare, *carnelasciale, carnasciale*, form a series exactly parallel to **carnem levare, *carne levare, carnelevale, carnevale*. Other names having a similar reference are, for Shrove Tuesday, *carnicapium* ‘flesh-taking’, and *carnivora* [*dies*]; for Lent or its beginning, *carniprivium, carnisprivium, privicarnium, < privare* to deprive. In all these, ‘flesh’ means meat, and that it was understood to mean the same in *carnelevare* is shown by many early quotations in Du Cange; e.g. in a MS. of beg. of 13th cent. ‘De ludo Carnelevar. In Dominica dimissionis carnis,’ etc. Also ‘Dominica ad vel ante carnes tollendas’; with which compare the Spanish *carnes tolendas*, ‘shrove-tide’. We must therefore entirely reject the suggestion founded on another sense of *levare*, ‘to relieve, ease’, that *carnelevarium* meant ‘the solace of the flesh (i.e. body)’ before the austerities of Lent. The explanations ‘farewell flesh, farewell to flesh’ (from Latin *vale*) found already in Florio, and ‘down with flesh!’ (from French *aval*), belong to the domain of popular etymology. (Compare Dr. Chance in Notes & Queries s. 7 IV. 82.)

Notice how there’s another folk myth in French about meaning ‘down with flesh!’. [Larousse says that the etymology of its *carnaval*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/carnaval/13348?q=carnaval#13187) is from:

> (italien *carnevale*, mardi gras, du latin médiéval *carnelevare*, ôter la viande)

(Where *ôter* there means ‘abstain’ from Latin *obstare*, obstain, abstain.)

The [Portuguese *carnaval*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carnaval) derives from the Italian by way of the French, if anyone cares:

> (francês *carnaval*, do italiano *carnevale*, de *carnelevare*, retirar a carne)
>
> — "carnaval", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carnaval [consultado em 26-08-2018].

[Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carnaval#Dutch) also has the *carnaval* spelling via French, while [German](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Karneval) spells it *Karneval* via Italian.

## Summary

- *Cannibal* has nothing to do with the Great Khan nor with dogs. Rather, it’s about the Caribbean autochthons.
- *Carnival* has nothing to do with saying farewell although it does have an etymon meaning meat or flesh.